Analysing tensorflow profiler data
I am trying to optimise a model training and I have collected some data through the profiler. I need some help interpreting and finding the probable cause for the data displayed in the profiler
Device operations data, host operations data, training step flame graph can you look at the above data collected and help me understand what is causing so many memory communications while the train step is in process. Is there any explanation for the large amounts of idle time on the cpu(host) and gpu(device)?
